# Match multiple expressions of the same type in ANTL4

Tags: antlr, antlr4

Let's say we want to use a function that adds several arguments, then how to structure ANTLR4 grammar to collect and pass all sub-expressions at once?

Bellow is example grammar to illustrate the point, note all terms for '+' are collected and passed into expression at once vs all terms for '*' are recursively evaluated.

[image]

```
grammar calc;

stats: exp*;

exp
    : INT ('+' INT)+
    | exp ('*' exp)+
    | INT
    ;

INT: [0-9]+;
WS: [ \n]+ -> skip;
```

NOTE: the above grammar cheats by placing INT around '+' operator (instead of exp as around '*').

Here is a ***paintbrushed*** diagram of (what I think) target parse tree would look like for expression `1*2+2*2+3*3`:

[image]

Comment: I'm afraid your question is not clear enough for us to be able to help. It looks like you know how to achieve your goal (the '+' parse tree). Can you explain what you would like to get and what the hurdle is ? Maybe a representative example expression and the desired parse tree would help.

Comment: Added more context and diagram (specifically '+' parse tree in above diagram cannot accept expressions only numbers, so 2+2 works but 2+(2*2) will not)

Answer (score 0):

The grammar below should (almost) produce the parse tree you have drawn. This is a fairly common way of managing n-ary operators and priorities.

```
exp : add ;
add : mult ('+' mult)* ;
mult : term ('*' term)* ;
term : ( '(' exp ')' ) | INT ;
```

'Hope this helps!

Comment: Not 100% happy with this, as it forces to structure expression to specify the operator precedence. In the above it's very simple to specify AND change the precedence by simply rendering the line with '+' and '*'

Comment: i think you nailed the description, this question came up on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24232770/n-ary-operator-parsing